# CSS set div 'top' with jquery from div 'height'

Tags: jquery, css

I have a template with lots of absolute positioning, now my main text div has a dynamic height and I need a dynamic footer which follows after this.

I tried to set the top state of the footer div with the height value from the text div.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#footer").top($("#text").height());
    </script>
```

Unfortunately, Chrome Dev tools throws the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'top'
>   (anonymous function)

So any idea or help for my problem?

Edit:

So i tried

```
 $('#footer').css('top', $('#text').outerHeight() + 'px');
```

and it works well, is it possible to add some px to this top value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will need to set the css property 'top' on the #footer div, not call .top() on the div itself.

```
$("#footer").css('top', $("#text").height() + "px");
```

or along those lines

Comment: brings me >Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: you probably need to pop the unit on the backend of height() as it only returns the numeric representation of the value.

Comment: it was a problem of my  "jQuery(document).ready(function($){" I fixed it

Answer (score 6):

Replace `.top` with `.offset({top: somenumber})`

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: This one worked for me. I'm not sure if the .css version failed because I had existing css on the element but, regardless, this one seems to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#footer').css('top', $('#text').outerHeight() + 'px');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $('#footer').style.css("top",$('#text').style.css("height"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is correct, jQuery doesn't abstract a method `top`. You would rather use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) like

```
$('#footer').css('top', $('#text').height());
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if the `top` css property isn't explicity set?

Comment: @mblase75: jQuery (the browser actually), would just create that css property if it's not already filled. More correctly, all css properties are available anytime, it just depends whether or not those have a value or not.

Comment: I misread the question -- however, it might be worth pointing out the (unlikely here) complication that would result if both `top` and `bottom` css properties are set at the same time. If the OP is manipulating someone else's code, then the `bottom` property should be explicitly cleared to be safe.